# between operator not working properly mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

am trying to findout data between two queries
my database contains date in datetime,so i converted it
this is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM payments
LEFT JOIN rentals ON payments.rental_id=rentals.rental_id
WHERE trim(DATE_FORMAT(payments.payment_date,'%d/%m/%Y%'))
          BETWEEN "28/05/2005" AND "10/06/2005"
```

this brings empty result ,but if i changed date to `30/06/2005` then its working
am confused ,please help

Comment: Not enough info to reproduce, please provide an MCVE.

Comment: I..e add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: why everybody negative marking without reading it

Comment: for avoid downvote you should also add  a table schema, data sample and the expetced  result

Comment: You are using string compare, so your statement is like `WHERE number_column BETWEEN 8 AND 5`. Change it to date compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should convert string to date and not date to string otherwise you compare string using between and not date

```
  SELECT *
  FROM payments
  LEFT JOIN rentals ON payments.rental_id=rentals.rental_id
  WHERE payments.payment_date 
            BETWEEN str_to_date("28/05/2005", '%d/%m/%Y')  
                AND  str_to_date("10/06/2005", '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: @user7441072   .. i don't understand you comment .?  .

Comment: can use another AND condition in where clause?

Comment: SELECT * FROM payments LEFT JOIN rentals ON payments.rental_id=rentals.rental_id LEFT JOIN inventory ON rentals.inventory_id=rentals.inventory_id WHERE payments.payment_date BETWEEN str_to_date("28/05/2005", '%d/%m/%Y') AND str_to_date("10/06/2005", '%d/%m/%Y') HAVING inventory.Kind='DVD'

Comment: Got,thanks  SELECT COUNT(rentals.rental_id) FROM payments LEFT JOIN rentals ON payments.rental_id=rentals.rental_id LEFT JOIN inventory ON rentals.inventory_id=inventory.inventory_id WHERE payments.payment_date BETWEEN str_to_date("28/05/2005", '%d/%m/%Y') AND str_to_date("10/06/2005", '%d/%m/%Y') AND inventory.Kind='DVD'

Comment: ,can you come in stack overflow chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167079/discussion-between-user7441072-and-scaisedge).